# socket.io server stops running if I close the terminal window?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hi,

I installed socket.io on my shared server and seems to be working fine. I start it by entering this command on my terminal on cpanel: `/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node index.js`

The problem is that once I close the terminal window the server will stop and then my app wont work anymore! Does it mean I must keep my terminal window open in order to have it work 24/7? Thats out of the question! Is there any alternative for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Node question or a Socket.io question.  It’s an OS question.

If you are using a Unix or Unix-like system, look into [`nohup`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

If you are using a Windows system, look into using a Unix or Unix-like system.

Comment: Im on a linux centos. I tried your solution but maybe Im not getting it right. I am executing my command like this `nohup /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node index.js` but still when I close the window the nodejs server goes offline.

Comment: Try it like this: `nohup /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node index.js &`

Comment: sorry, it didnt work. It still stops as I exit the terminal.